# Change a question on a form based on cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Completely new to coding and am teaching myself as I go along. Pretty chuffed with what I have achieved so far and now want to push my boundaries of learning!

So context - I organise youth football tournaments. Teams enter the tournament via a google form. The form goes into a google sheet that I then use formulas to ensure I can see how many teams have entered per each age group. Each age group has a maximum number of teams it can have in the tournament. The link to a live form is https://forms.gle/8VoBddM8AAJMFXqM7

What I want to do

At the moment, I have to manually edit the form when an age group becomes close to being full. For example clubs can enter a max of two teams. When there is only one space left, I currently manually have to delete the option to enter 2 teams ensuring one 1 team can be entered. This sometimes results in me not being able to do it fast enough and 2 teams being entered even though there is only 1 space available. So it all becomes a bit messy

So - is there code that when a cell in sheets equals a specific number, the google form automatically deletes the option to enter 2 teams so I don't have this issue?

Secondly.......

When an age group becomes full, I have to manually edit the form to direct any future entries for that age group to a different section of the form for teams to fill out a reserve list form. Like the above, I sometimes can't do this quickly enough. So, is there any code I can use to automatically direct the user to a different section of the form based on the value of a cell in sheets?

So in summary

One thing I need is to automatically delete an option in forms based on a cell value in sheets. And secondly, automatically redirect to a different section in forms based on a cell value in sheets

I am new to all this and learning so please be kind! :)

Comment: Welcome. The answer to both questions is "Yes". But it requires a script (code) to be developed and attached to the Responses spreadsheet; the script would be written to recognise the triggers that you have described and then update the Form accordingly.

Comment: You have asked two quite separate questions. The code (for each question) has two parts: 1) code to analyse sheets data to detect a threshold and 2) code to modify the Form. If you are new to coding, then I respectfully suggest that you choose one question and begin with the "threshold" code. You may (or not) find that your description of each threshold is somewhat oversimplified. If you would like some practical help, then please identify the focus issue, articulate the threshold can be determined, and share a COPY of your spreadsheet (remove any private or confidential data).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. The link to the sheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q1GGAkazk55kCwtzkRnqSseJOgTyK89JINC16fRfE0w/edit?usp=sharing. I have deleted all personal information. All form entries go to Raw Data and then I use formula to create specific age group sheets. The information on Overview is what I would need to inform the changes on the form. E.g when a cell on Column F equals 1, i will need the respective question on the form to only allow the user to submit one team. When a cell in Column F equals 0 it needs to redirect to relevant reserve list section

Answer (score 0):

You want to make changes to a Form based on certain values that arise from Form Submissions. This answer does attempt to address the Form changes (for not the least reason that the structure of the Form is not known) but focuses on recognising threshold events that will give rise to script to modify the Form.

**THRESHOLDS**

You want to identify Age Groups where, after a new form is submitted, the "Number of Places Left" is either 1 or 0.

Consider that there might be many ways to do this, and this script is one approach.

**Key elements**

- the function must be installed as `onFormSubmit`
- the actual form submission does not appear to be important (though this may change as the script is further enhanced)
- the data retrieved from Overview includes Column B->F because, once the value (Column F) is evaluated, one must identify the relevant Age group (Column B)
- a loop, IF statement and logger statement is used to identify instances where the threshold has been reached - this is the simplest possible approach; other methods such as `indexOf` and/or `switch` could be used to identify the threshold and the resulting action.
- Note that **ALL** instances of the thresholds are returned; the result is not limited to the particular instance generated by the latest form response. Possibly/probably this could be done if necessary.

---

```
function so6047592901() {

  // sample of onFormSubmit to check 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var overview = ss.getSheetByName("Overview");


  // get the data
  var startRow=3
  var startCol=2
  var rows = 19
  var cols = 5
  var data =  overview.getRange(startRow, startCol, rows, cols);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: data range = "+data.getA1Notation());
  var values = data.getValues();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: number values = "+values)


  // test for places left = 1
  var test1left = "1";
  // test for places left = 0
  var test0left = "0";

  for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    // test for the Age Group
     var ageGrp = values[i][0]
    if (values[i][4] == test1left) {
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Places Left = "+values[i][4]+", i:"+i+" , Age group is "+ageGrp);
    }
    if (values[i][4] == test0left){
      Logger.log("DEBUG: Places Left = "+values[i][4]+", i:"+i+" , Age group is "+ageGrp);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay great - thanks for this. That looks like it will identify a threshold. How does this then edit the form? The link to the form in edit version is https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1uzDiGWlob7--RAicjvE9C3hFtDKpygxQn8MNpQKPgQg/edit?usp=sharing. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Just checking back in to see if your saw my last comment? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### You can edit your form automatically by using Apps Scripts.

For example lets assume I have 5 spots available for the first 5 people to claim them using my form. After all available spots have been claimed, I want to remove the "claim spot" item from the form. I can achieve this by running a check function every time someone submits a response.

#### Example:

1. From your response spreadsheet [create a bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script)
2. In the script create a function to check (true or false) if you still have available spots.

```js
function spotsAvailable(ss) {
    var maxSpots = 5;

    // Get response sheet.
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    var lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();

    // Count the spots claimed
    var a1Notation = "B2:B" + lastRow;
    var claims = 0;
    ss.getRange(a1Notation).getValues().forEach(
        (claim) => {
            if (claim == "Yes") {
                claims++
            }
            return claims
        });
    // Return true if there are available spots, else false
    if (claims < maxSpots) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

3. Create the function that will be triggered on form submit:

```js
function changeForm() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

    if (spotsAvailable(ss) == false) {
        // If no more spots remove claim spot item from form
        var items = form.getItems();
        // Item index one (1) is our multiple selection question
        // You can get items by id, or by index.
        form.deleteItem(1);
    }

}
```

4. [Install the trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to run "On Form Submit".
5. Relax knowing only the max spots can be claimed, your script took care of it for you.

---

#### Notes:

Please do note this is just an example, and depending on your particular needs, you can use any of the available methods in the Apps Script Services, which are referenced below...

---

**Recommended reading:**

- [Apps Script Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms)
- [Apps Script Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [G Suite Application Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers)

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this will work for how I want it to do as i have multiple age groups each with their own limit. I use one form that then gives the user the option to select the age group they want to enter. This then takes them to a section. The above script I don't think will work. You can view the form in editable format at https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1uzDiGWlob7--RAicjvE9C3hFtDKpygxQn8MNpQKPgQg/edit?usp=sharing and then the responses sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q1GGAkazk55kCwtzkRnqSseJOgTyK89JINC16fRfE0w/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Did you see this comment? Thanks

Comment: You have a very large form, with many sections, (very well organized) and your sheets seem to have some order to it (start with "Under ") so I guess you can figure out a logic to check your age group availability. My answer is meant to show you a way how you can check if (your conditions) are met, and if so, change the content of the form itself. Removing sections, adding them, etc... Give it a shot using the references mentioned and the code provided and develop a script to start with. Try to break it down to the minimum, providing extra stuff is unnecessary and leads to confusion.